# How to add a field in Django model?

Tags: python, django

In Django, if I have a model which has 4 fields, but now I want to add a new field, how do I keep the data in the old model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use South

```
pip install South
```

firstly, keep your django models match your current database tables exactly, then run:

```
python manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial
python manage.py migrate myapp --fake 
#Make changes to your django model (add new field)
python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto 
python manage.py migrate myapp
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to perform a "migration", and the current best way to do this in Django is with a tool called [South](http://south.aeracode.org/).

Check out [their tutorial](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/index.html). Make sure you make a copy of your db before you do this, since you may mess something up if it's your first time using South.